# MongoDB recursive search (folder tree)

Tags: mongodb, search, recursion

I have a collection of folder tree and I want to get children for folder.
Here is my document structure

```
{"_id":"1","metadata":{"parents":[]}}

{"_id":"2","metadata":{"parents":["1"]}}

{"_id":"3","metadata":{"parents":["2","1"]}}

{"_id":"4","metadata":{"parents":["2","1"]}}

{"_id":"5","metadata":{"parents":["4","2"]}}
```

F.e. I want to get all children of document with `id  = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your use case, `MongoDB v3.4` provides an **aggregation** pipeline operator called `$graphLookup`. The aggregation operator is able to perform a recursive search on a collection. See more definiton on [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) definition.